# How to pass a data from an excel file and use it as an argument

Tags: javascript, protractor

I am trying to get the value from a cell in an excel file and pass it as a parameter to one of my methods

I am able to enter the `site_num` if I just hard code the parameter and move it outside the `.then(function)` of `readFile`
Ex. `export_page.enterSiteId('20003');`

```
    base_page.clickExportLink(); //Clicking the export link

    var workbook = new Excel.Workbook();
    workbook.xlsx.readFile('D:\\Project1\\testdata\\Book1.xlsx').then(function () {

        var worksheet1 = workbook.getWorksheet('Sheet2');
        var Row = worksheet1.getRow(1);
        site_num = Row.getCell(2).value;
        export_page.enterSiteId(site_num); //here is the problem where, it wont enter the value
        console.log(site_num); //i am able to print the value

        var worksheet2 = workbook.getWorksheet('Sheet1');
        for (var i = 2; i < worksheet2.rowCount; i++) {

            var Row = worksheet2.getRow(i);
            site_field = Row.getCell(1).value;
            cust_field = Row.getCell(2).value;
            status = Row.getCell(3).value;

            template.customField(cust_field);
        }
    });

    export_page.clickSearchBtn();  //Click the search button after the site_num is entered
```

It says that the locator where to enter the `site_num` could not be found.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is whatever your 'workbook' library is doing is asynchronous, so try this

```
workbook.xlsx.readFile('D:\\Project1\\testdata\\Book1.xlsx').then(async function () {

    var worksheet1 = await workbook.getWorksheet('Sheet2');
    var Row = await worksheet1.getRow(1);
    site_num = await Row.getCell(2).value;
    await export_page.enterSiteId(site_num);
    console.log(site_num);

    var worksheet2 = await workbook.getWorksheet('Sheet1');
    for (var i = 2; i < worksheet2.rowCount; i++) {

        var Row = await worksheet2.getRow(i);
        site_field = await Row.getCell(1).value;
        cust_field = await Row.getCell(2).value;
        status = await Row.getCell(3).value;

        await template.customField(cust_field);
    }
});

export_page.clickSearchBtn();  //Click the search button after the site_num is entered
```

Comment: I tried it but the same error is displayed. by the way, the site im testing is non-angular. Anyway i already found the solution by using the readFile in a beforeAll() then just use the workbook in the it block

Comment: @CelesP Glad you made your code work. I personally use `excel-as-json` package for conversion and I like it